# VBScript: Reading through a dictionary in a Session variable

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I'm trying to store a list of table items in a Session variable to keep track of the last state (CHECKED or UNCHECKED) of the item's checkbox.

I start out by setting all values to UNCHECKED the first time the users loads the page. This part of the code seems to work:

```
model = Request.querystring("model")

If IsEmpty(Session(model)) Then

    Set dicX = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    sqlStr = "SELECT DISTINCT level FROM IFPDB WHERE IFPDB.model='"
    sqlStr = sqlStr & model
    sqlStr = sqlStr & "'"

    Set objRS = objConn.Execute(sqlStr)

    ' For each unique level get all of that levels menu names       
    Do While (Not objRS.EOF)
        level = objRS("level")
        dicX.Add level, CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

        ' for each menu name set the initial state to OFF
        sqlStr2 = "SELECT * FROM IFPDB WHERE IFPDB.model='"
        sqlStr2 = sqlStr2 & model
        sqlStr2 = sqlStr2 & "' AND IFPDB.level='"
        sqlStr2 = sqlStr2 & level_name
        sqlStr2 = sqlStr2 & "'"

        Set objRS2 = objConn.Execute(sqlStr2)

        Do While (Not objRS2.EOF)
            menu_item = objRS2("menu_names")
            dicX(level).Add menu_item, CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

            ' add a dictionary item
            dicX(level)(menu_item).Add "menu_state", "UNCHECKED"

            objRS2.MoveNext
        Loop

        objRS.MoveNext
    Loop

    Set Session(model) = dicX
End If
```

The problem now comes when I try to read any of these values. No matter how I've tried to access them I get "Object_required:_'[undefined]'"

I've tried

```
' Check the last state of this option
menu_name = objResult("menu_names")
response.write(menu_name & "<br>") ' writes correctly

If Not IsEmpty(Session(model))
 my_state = Session(model)(current_level)(menu_name).Item("menu_state")   ' dies here
 response.write(my_state & "<br>")
End If

' tried these as well
my_state = Session(model)(current_level)(menu_name)("menu_state")
'and
my_state = Session(model)(current_level).Item(menu_name).Item("menu_state")
'and others
```

I guess I just don't know how to read that Session variable that I made. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you aware that you use a variable `level` and `level_name`? If the latter is never set to a certain value, the query will fail and objRS2 is never set with any data (except when by an happy accident there is a IFPDB.level with value '').

Comment: level and level_name are assumed to be always set because they are a required part of the database table.

Comment: lol! I found what you were talking about the hard way, after an hour. The variable level magically became the variable level_name. I guess that makes the case for using Explicit and Dim'ing all variables...

Comment: You should never create or run scripts without Option Explicit. Everytime you do that, you are saddening a baby-bunny. We don't want that, do we? Nevertheless, I like your use of chaining Dictionaries and the use of multiple parenthesis calling them. I doubt if it is a good pattern, but personally, I like it.

Answer (score 1):

See:
[Can I store a Scripting Dictionary in a session variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076165/can-i-store-a-scripting-dictionary-in-a-session-variable)

You have to extract the dictionary from the session and put in into a fresh variable.

```
dim state
set state = Session(model)
```

You are also missing the 'item' part:

```
my_state = state.item(current_level).item(menu_name).item("menu_state")
```

Comment: Thanks, this may be a big help. I'll try it out today.

Comment: Good to hear! Could you flag this post as the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use Session("model") instead of Session(model).

Comment: Sorry, I should have shown that I was getting that from :           model = Request.querystring("model")

Comment: I really have no idea what you mean in this comment.