# Dictionary Object Losing its Contents Classic ASP

Tags: object, vbscript, asp-classic, session-variables

```
<%@ language = "VBScript"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
Username:<br> <input type = "text" name = "user"/><br>
Password:<br> <input type = "password" name = "pass"/><br>
<input type = "submit" name = "register_button" value = "Register"/>
<input type = "submit" name = "submit_button" value = "Submit"/>
</form> 

<%
set credentials = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
set Session("credentials") = credentials 

if Request.form("register_button") <> "" then
    dim user
    dim pass
    pass = Request.form("pass")
    user = Request.form("user")

    Session("credentials").Add user, pass   
end if

if Request.form("submit_button") <> "" then 
    dim userd
    dim passd
    passd = Request.form("pass")
    userd = Request.form("user")
    if Session("credentials").Exists(userd) = true then
        if Session("credentials").Item(userd) = passd then
            Response.Write("ACCESS GRANTED")
        else 
            Response.Write("ACCESS DENIED")
        end if
    else
        Response.Write("USERNAME DOES NOT EXIST")
    end if
end if
%>

</body>
</html>
```

So this is a basic login page I created using Classic ASP. When I type in a user and pass, then click Register, it stores the username and password in the Dictionary no problem. But, when I click the submit button (after filling in the registered credentials), somehow the contents of the dictionary get deleted. So, it fails the **"if Session("credentials").Exists(userd) = true then"** statement. I even tried making "credentials" a normal variable, without using Session. It still won't work, the dictionary's contents just get deleted. How can I overcome this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would rethink this approach; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076165/can-i-store-a-scripting-dictionary-in-a-session-variable

Comment: Well because I'm still a beginner in ASP, I only wanted to store the credentials in a Dictionary. I want to avoid using Databases for the time being. With that said, what approach do you suggest I should take? Would storing the credentials in a query string work? I'm just doing this for learning purposes so it doesn't have to be secure.

Comment: The session is already like a dictionary so I would just store the values directly; Session("pass") = "xyz" / Session("user") = "bob"

Comment: Interesting, I'll give it a shot

Comment: @AlexK. better post this as answer, sometimes the most simple things evade us.

Answer (score 0):

this first
credentials.Add user, pass

set Session("credentials") = credentials
should be after

Comment: Hey George, welcome on board :) may you please further elaborate on your answer. A first step would be to format code lines, a second step would be to add more detailed instructions on what to do.

Comment: please consider to provide more description. and format your post accordingly